# Wandering drop down when adding filter in review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface, jquery

I just noticed this when I was trying to add a filter to the review queue:
[image: Wandering drop down]

Steps to reproduce:

- Open any review queue
- Click 'filter' and select the 'Tag' textbox
- Type in a tag and quickly hit enter (it should be a short one, one that you can type before the ajax call completes).

The page will update with the filter, and a moment later, the auto-complete drop down will appear.

---

Occasionally, if you hit enter *after* the drop down appears, the page will update with the filter, but the auto-complete drop down will remain:

[image: Wandering drop down]

This is a minor bug, since it doesn't prevent me from reviewing at all, but I figured I'd bring it up.

Comment: Seen this as well, it *is* annoying.

Comment: looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev 2013.7.4.814